# Regular Expression not capturing expected strings

Tags: c#, regex

The pattern:

```
000[0-9]Text(.*)?000[0-9]Font
```

> ISystem, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   -System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary     head version count comparer
>   
>   System.Collections.IComparer
>   
>   
>   0001      Text          QSystem.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   0001Center                System.Drawing.PointF     x y        \
>   ˆ=mÀÉ@               0001Expansion                System.Drawing.SizeF
>   width height        Ì6 AÃ»Y?               0001Color
>   System.Drawing.Color     name value knownColor state               ÿ
>   0001Text     YPARTIAL RELEASE IN  09/2573, 09/2835, 09/2908, 11/86, 
>   11/1741, 11/1803, 11/2484, 11/2765                    0001Font
>   System.Drawing.Font     Name Size Style Unit
>   System.Drawing.FontStyle     System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit
>   Microsoft Sans Serif  @A èÿÿÿ System.Drawing.FontStyle     value__
>   çÿÿÿ System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit     value__
>   0001Charset                          0001TextOrientation
>   0002                    !    0002Center "    #    "       )\ >{ Î@ #
>   $    0002Expansion %    &    %       )\@Ãõ(? &        '    0002Color
>   (    )    (           ÿ         )        *    0002Text +    12/452, 
>   12/1629 ,    ,        -    0002Font .    /    .        0    Microsoft
>   Sans Serif  @A Ïÿÿÿèÿÿÿ     Îÿÿÿçÿÿÿ     /        3    0002Charset
>   4    4        5    0002TextOrientation       6    6        7    0003
>   9    9        :    0003Center ;    <    ;       ö(\¿ …ËÀ <        =
>   0003Expansion >    ?    >       …ë @   ? ?        @    0003Color A
>   B    A                %    B        C    0003Text D    SATISFACTION 
>   IN  13/25 E    E        F    0003Font G    H    G        I
>   Microsoft Sans Serif  @A ¶ÿÿÿèÿÿÿ     µÿÿÿçÿÿÿ     H        L
>   0003Charset       M    M        N    0003TextOrientation

What i am expecting:

- `YPARTIAL RELEASE IN 09/2573, 09/2835, 09/2908, 11/86, 11/1741, 11/1803, 11/2484, 11/2765`
- `12/452, 12/1629 , , -`
- `D SATISFACTION IN 13/25 E E F`

In the .NET regex engine it returns `null`.

What I get in Expresso:

```
 YPARTIAL RELEASE IN  09/2573, 09/2835, 09/2908, 11/86,  11/1741, 11/1803, 11/2484, 11/2765                    0001Font                System.Drawing.Font     Name Size Style Unit      System.Drawing.FontStyle     System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit              Microsoft Sans Serif  @A èÿÿÿ System.Drawing.FontStyle     value__           çÿÿÿ System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit     value__                         0001Charset                          0001TextOrientation                          0002                    !    0002Center "    #    "       )\ >{ Î@ #        $    0002Expansion %    &    %       )\@Ãõ(? &        '    0002Color (    )    (           ÿ         )        *    0002Text +    12/452,  12/1629 ,    ,        -    0002Font .    /    .        0    Microsoft Sans Serif  @A Ïÿÿÿèÿÿÿ     Îÿÿÿçÿÿÿ     /        3    0002Charset       4    4        5    0002TextOrientation       6    6        7    0003      9    9        :    0003Center ;    <    ;       ö(\¿ …ËÀ <        =    0003Expansion >    ?    >       …ë @   ? ?        @    0003Color A    B    A                %    B        C    0003Text D    SATISFACTION  IN  13/25 E    E        F
```

C# code

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"000\dText(.*)?000\dFont", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(test))
{
     if(match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value.IndexOf("System") < 0)
        details += match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value.Trim() + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Replace `RegexOptions.Multiline` with `RegexOptions.Singleline` if your input spans across multiple lines. Also, `.Captures[0]` is redundant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew replaced Regex reg = new Regex(@"000\dText(.*)?000\dFont", RegexOptions.Singleline);

still no matches

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [`RegexOptions.Multiline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) only changes the meaning of `^` and `$`, which OP is not using: "Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so they match at the beginning and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the beginning and end of the entire string"

Comment: @SamIam wouldn't (.*) capture the spaces?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? seems like a legit question to me?

Comment: Agree, it is a valid question. Just formatting is a bit off (please check if you can fix the sample text layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@"000[0-9]Text\b(.*?)000[0-9]Font\b"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=000%5B0-9%5DText%5Cb(.*%3F)000%5B0-9%5DFont%5Cb&i=ISystem%2C%20Version%3D2.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Db77a5c561934e089%20%20%20%20%20-System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary%20%20%20%20%20head%20version%20count%20comparer%20%20%20%20%3CSystem.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary%2BDictionaryNode%20%20%20%20%20%20%20System.Collections.IComparer%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSystem.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary%2BDictionaryNode%20%20%20%20%20key%20value%20next%20%20%20%3CSystem.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary%2BDictionaryNode%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200001%20%20%20%20%20%20Text%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20QSystem.Drawing%2C%20Version%3D2.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Db03f5f7f11d50a3a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200001Center%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20System.Drawing.PointF%20%20%20%20%20x%20y%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%20%CB%86%3Dm%C3%80%C3%89%40%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200001Expansion%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20System.Drawing.SizeF%20%20%20%20%20width%20height%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%C3%8C6%20A%C3%83%C2%BBY%3F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200001Color%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20System.Drawing.Color%20%20%20%20%20name%20value%20knownColor%20state%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%C2%A0%20%20%C3%BF%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A0001Text%20%20%20%20%20YPARTIAL%20RELEASE%20IN%20%2009%2F2573%2C%2009%2F2835%2C%2009%2F2908%2C%2011%2F86%2C%20%2011%2F1741%2C%2011%2F1803%2C%2011%2F2484%2C%2011%2F2765%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200001Font%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20System.Drawing.Font%20%20%20%20%20Name%20Size%20Style%20Unit%20%20%20%20%20%20System.Drawing.FontStyle%20%20%20%20%20System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Microsoft%20Sans%20Serif%20%20%40A%20%C3%A8%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF%20System.Drawing.FontStyle%20%20%20%20%20value__%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%C3%A7%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF%20System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit%20%20%20%20%20value__%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200001Charset%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200001TextOrientation%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200002%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20!%20%20%20%200002Center%20%22%20%20%20%20%23%20%20%20%20%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%5C%20%3E%7B%20%C3%8E%40%20%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%20%20%20%200002Expansion%20%25%20%20%20%20%26%20%20%20%20%25%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%5C%C2%8F%40%C3%83%C3%B5(%3F%20%26%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%20%20%20%200002Color%20(%20%20%20%20)%20%20%20%20(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%C2%A0%20%20%C3%BF%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*%20%20%20%200002Text%20%2B%20%20%20%2012%2F452%2C%20%2012%2F1629%20%2C%20%20%20%20%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%20%20%200002Font%20.%20%20%20%20%2F%20%20%20%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200%20%20%20%20Microsoft%20Sans%20Serif%20%20%40A%20%C3%8F%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%A8%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF%20%20%20%20%20%C3%8E%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%A7%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF%20%20%20%20%20%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%203%20%20%20%200002Charset%20%20%20%20%20%20%204%20%20%20%204%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%205%20%20%20%200002TextOrientation%20%20%20%20%20%20%206%20%20%20%206%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%207%20%20%20%200003%20%20%20%20%20%209%20%20%20%209%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%20%20%200003Center%20%3B%20%20%20%20%3C%20%20%20%20%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%C3%B6(%5C%C2%BF%20%E2%80%A6%C3%8B%C3%80%20%3C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20%20%20%200003Expansion%20%3E%20%20%20%20%3F%20%20%20%20%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%E2%80%A6%C3%AB%20%40%20%20%20%3F%20%3F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40%20%20%20%200003Color%20A%20%20%20%20B%20%20%20%20A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%25%20%20%20%20B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C%20%20%20%200003Text%20D%20%20%20%20SATISFACTION%20%20IN%20%2013%2F25%20E%20%20%20%20E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20F%20%20%20%200003Font%20G%20%20%20%20H%20%20%20%20G%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20I%20%20%20%20Microsoft%20Sans%20Serif%20%20%40A%20%C2%B6%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%A8%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF%20%20%20%20%20%C2%B5%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%A7%C3%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF%20%20%20%20%20H%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20L%20%20%20%200003Charset%20%20%20%20%20%20%20M%20%20%20%20M%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20N%20%20%20%200003TextOrientation%20%20%20%20)

Two points:

- The `(.*)?` is a greedy matching pattern that matches up to the last `000` + digit, but optional (`?`, one or zero). You need to change to the lazy dot matching, `.*?`.
- The `Text` should be followed with a word boundary, you may match the `0001TextOrientation` block.

[image]

Comment: Just do not remember to remove `.Captures[0]` in both lines. `match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value` = `match.Groups[1].Value`.